# My account should likely be deleted

Tags: support

Everything I have done in the last two days has been closed, wrong or deleted. So truly, as my days are becoming here a waste of my time.

You are welcome to delete my account as that would likely be the best solution .

Comment: Checking your reputation history you have received nothing but upvotes to all your answers except one.

Comment: the last 6 answers posted by you were deleted by yourself, in response to others' comments about your answer being wrong. There's no shame about being wrong about something and learning from it - that's why I'm still here a decade later

Comment: Please don't leave, your answers are usually spot on.

Comment: @John you have made some tremendous contributions to the Super User community, and they are genuinely appreciated. However, as I said before in a comment that most community members can't see, the quality of our solutions should take precedence over the **quantity** of our answers. You delete a *lot* of your answers, presumably because they actually receive a downvote (like [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1529131/650163)). Perhaps if you focused your attention on submitting fewer high-quality answers rather than several each day, you wouldn't have that problem. Just something to consider.

Comment: *"I get rid of unnecessary answers..."* But **that** is my point, good sir. It might be prudent to slow down just a bit so that you don't *submit* unnecessary answers in the first place. When you post an answer *very* quickly that is less than twenty words and has no references, it really shouldn't be a big surprise when it receives a downvote. That probably should have been posted as a comment, instead.

Comment: Once again @John, your Super User contributions are terrific, **but** if you still find yourself deleting answers on even a semi-regular basis, you probably need to slow down a bit more.  Quality > quantity.

Comment: That isn't entirely true, good sir. From what I can see, you authored 29 answers within a 10-day period. That isn't exactly a conservative approach. As I said before @John, your Super User contributions are stellar, and we definitely wouldn't want to lose your valuable input. At the same time, if you still find yourself posting so quickly that you decide to completely delete the proposed solution because someone has the audacity to downvote your answer, perhaps it was written just a *bit* too quickly.

Comment: @John, what I'm hearing is that you conveniently ignore the positive feedback intertwined with constructive criticism, and are essentially a "glass half empty" type of person.  That's unfortunate, but not too surprising based upon the original Meta post that you authored (directly above) that was rather melodramatic.  Perhaps you should re-read the answer that Mokubai posted, because you haven't really followed his advice.  That being said, please feel free to populate the Super User realm with as many answers as you want, and best of luck to you in the future.

Answer (score 10):

The best way to delete you account is to do it yourself. Due to having significant reputation the deletion may have to be manually approved by someone at Stack Exchange so it may take a little longer.  Instructions can be found at the bottom of this post and in the [help centre](https://superuser.com/help).

Despite appearances we do actually *want* you to stay. You appear to honestly want to help people which is absolutely awesome. We *need* people to help us grow and keep the community alive. You've probably noticed that a good few questions pass through with low views and no answers and are trying to help by posting something to help the asker. Again, that is *awesome*.

The problem is that people who browse the answers want to see evidence that an answer will actually solve the problem asked. We prefer longer and more well thought out answers. We like to solve the problem for future users who come via a search engine and might not know what their exact problem is to begin with. Unless the question is exceptionally well written shorter answers are probably not going to help that so it is up to you as the person answering to get those future visitors. Being able to back up your answers with verifiable evidence is a great way to be certain that it is correct and future-proof.

That said, the decision is yours to make. You can either go through the process below or, if that does not work, message me below and I will schedule the deletion for you.

---

[How do I delete my account?](https://superuser.com/help/deleting-account)

> User deletion is irreversible! By sending this request, your votes will be revoked, and all of your content will be made anonymous.
>
> You should see a [Delete Profile](https://superuser.com/users/delete/current) option on your user profile by clicking the Edit Profile & Settings link at the top of your profile page:
>
> [image: self-delete from profile]
>
> Visit that page and read through the information there. Once you've done so, check the box to indicate that you understand the implications of deleting your profile and then click the Delete Profile button.
>
> If you have never posted or voted more than once on your profile, it will be immediately deleted. Otherwise, you will be scheduled for deletion. During that time, you can cancel the deletion request by visiting your profile and clicking the cancel link in the banner at the top. Otherwise, it will be deleted after 24 hours.